# How to encrypt data with AES 256 bit in java?

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have research many source code and find difficulty on how to specify block size in AES java? Does java support until 256 bits? I have search out php source code and it support until 256 bits AES encryption

This is the sample source code for AES encryption. Thanks all for helping me to figure out.
http://aesencryption.net/

Comment: see my comment below. i found that you simply need to create the SecretKeySpec as an "AES" key with a 32 byte key value. This puts it in AES256 mode.

Comment: There is no such thing as AES with a block size of 256 bits.  Did you mean key size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports **Rijndael** with a 256 block size. AES is a subset of Rijndael with key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits and *a block size of 128 bits*. So saying that PHP supports AES with a blocksize of 256 bit is a contradiction (i.e. incorrect).

Java SE (up to and including Java 9) by Oracle only supports AES with a 128 bit block size and all (3) AES key sizes, although you need the Unlimited Crypto files to use 192 and 256 bit encryption.

To use Rijndael with 256 bit block size you could use Bouncy Castle lightweight API, the different block sizes aren't added to the Bouncy Castle provider either:

```
new RijndaelEngine(256)
```

For Android you may want to use Spongy Castle instead.

Comment: And don't trust clickbait websites with fancy names.

Answer (score -3):

TRY IT:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String key = "1234567890ABCDEF";
        try {
            byte[] encrypt = encrypt("hello word",key);
            System.out.println(new String(encrypt));
            String decrypt = decrypt(encrypt, key);
            System.out.println(decrypt);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }

   public static byte[] encrypt(String message, String key1) throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(key1.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] message, String key1) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(key1.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(message);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
        return decryptedText;
    }
```

Comment: I found you use a SecretKeySpec for "AES" and supply 32 bytes of key. It looks like you are using a 16 byte key above which would be AES128. If you get the exception "InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size exception" its not because your code is wrong, it's because you aren't set up with a strong encryption policy. At lease this is what I found with Java, not sure if you will encounter this with Android.

Comment: Both the block size and key size of the given code is 128 bits so does not actually answer the OPs question, however poor.

Comment: TRY IT is not a good description of a solution. Besides that there are a lot of issues with your code, such as using ECB, forgetting to specify character encodings, explicitly specifying the SunJCE (@SlipperySeal which means it won't even run on Android :P), using a text string as key, printing out the ciphertext without encoding it first, bad exception handling... (then again, you did spell encrypt/decrypt correctly and did treat the ciphertext as binary string before decryption).